# In Delphi, How do I get an enumerator from LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.GloballyOpenPorts in the Firewall API

Tags: delphi, firewall

I am writing some code to see if there is a hole in the firewall exception list for **WinXP** and **Vista** for a specific port used by our client software.

I can see that I can use the `NetFwMgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.GloballyOpenPorts` to get a list of the current Open port exceptions.  But i can not figure out how to get that enumerated list in to something that I can use in my Delphi program.

My latest try is listed below. It's giving me an access violation when I use `port_list.Item`. I know that's wrong, it was mostly wishful thinking on my part. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function TFirewallUtility.IsPortInExceptionList(iPortNumber: integer): boolean;
var
  i, h: integer;
  port_list, port: OleVariant;
begin
  Result := False;
  port_list := mxFirewallManager.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.GloballyOpenPorts;
  for i := 0 to port_list.Count - 1 do
  begin
    port := port_list.Item[i];
    if (port.PortNumber = iPortNumber) then
    begin
      Result := True;
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think that I have it figured out.

I had to create a type library file of the hnetcfg.dll. I did that when I first started but have learned a lot about the firewall objects since then. It didn't work then, but its working now. You can create your own file from Component|Import Component. And then follow the wizard.

The wrapping code uses exceptions which I normally don't like to do, but I don't know how to tell whether an Interface that is returning an Interface is actually returning data that I can work off of... So that would be an improvement if somebody can point me in the right direction.

And now to the code, with a thanks to Jim for his response.

```
constructor TFirewallUtility.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  CoInitialize(nil);
  mxCurrentFirewallProfile := INetFwMgr(CreateOLEObject('HNetCfg.FwMgr')).LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile;
end;

function TFirewallUtility.IsPortInExceptionList(iPortNumber: integer): boolean;
begin
  try
    Result := mxCurrentFirewallProfile.GloballyOpenPorts.Item(iPortNumber, NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP).Port = iPortNumber;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function TFirewallUtility.IsPortEnabled(iPortNumber: integer): boolean;
begin
  try
    Result := mxCurrentFirewallProfile.GloballyOpenPorts.Item(iPortNumber, NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP).Enabled;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TFirewallUtility.SetPortEnabled(iPortNumber: integer; sPortName: string; xProtocol: TFirewallPortProtocol);
begin
  try
   mxCurrentFirewallProfile.GloballyOpenPorts.Item(iPortNumber, CFirewallPortProtocalConsts[xProtocol]).Enabled := True;
  except
    HaltIf(True, 'xFirewallManager.TFirewallUtility.IsPortEnabled: Port not in exception list.');
  end;
end;

procedure TFirewallUtility.AddPortToFirewall(sPortName: string; iPortNumber: Cardinal; xProtocol: TFirewallPortProtocol);
var
  port: INetFwOpenPort;
begin
  port := INetFwOpenPort(CreateOLEObject('HNetCfg.FWOpenPort'));
  port.Name := sPortName;
  port.Protocol := CFirewallPortProtocalConsts[xProtocol];
  port.Port := iPortNumber;
  port.Scope := NET_FW_SCOPE_ALL;
  port.Enabled := true;
  mxCurrentFirewallProfile.GloballyOpenPorts.Add(port);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the enum like this:

```
type
  IEnumVariant = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{00020404-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}']
    function Next(celt: LongWord; var rgvar : OleVariant;
                 pceltFetched: PLongWord): HResult; stdcall;
    function Skip(celt: LongWord): HResult; stdcall;
    function Reset: HResult; stdcall;
    function Clone(out Enum : IEnumVariant) : HResult; stdcall;
  end;

var
  Enum : IEnumVariant;
  Port : OleVariant;
  Count : Integer;
...
Count := 1;
IUnknown (Profile.GloballyOpenPorts._NewEnum).QueryInterface (IEnumVariant, Enum);
Enum.Reset;
while (Enum.Next (1, FirewallPort, @Count) = S_OK) do
  begin
  if (FirewallPort.Port = Port) then
    Exit (True)
  end;
```

Comment: Great thanks for that answer, Smasher! I got stuck in a similar problem and the IUnknown().QueryInterface trick worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Without setting up an application to test with, I'll suggest the following.  Let me know if it works.

I looked at the [C# example here](http://blogs.msdn.com/joncole/archive/2005/12/06/managed-classes-to-view-manipulate-the-windows-firewall.aspx), and it looks like you need to do something like the following:

```
Result := False;
port_enum := mxFirewallManager.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.GloballyOpenPorts._NewEnum;
while port_enum.MoveNext <> Null do // try assigned if that doesn't work
begin
  port = e.Current as INetFwOpenPort;
  if (port.PortNumber = iPortNumber) then
  begin
    Result := True;
    break;
  end;
end;
```

Not sure if that will compile, but the **_NewEnum**, **MoveNext** and **Current** are the members you want to use.